# display both queries and displaying all results into one

Tags: mysql

i am trying to display both queries and displaying all results into one

this is what i want to achieve [image: Results to be achieved]

this is the query i used, but union takes the common ones only, but i want both from query 1 and query 2.

```
select * from demo a where ( name, dob ) in ( select name,dob from demo group by name, dob having count(*) > 1 )
UNION
select * from demo a where ( name, mname) in ( select name, mname from demo group by name, mname having count(*) > 1 ) 
order by name ASC
```

Comment: did you try using UNION ALL?

Comment: using union all will pull 2 copies but i want only 1 copy

Comment: what do you mean when you say, "2 copies" ?